# Writing Object to File Output

Tags: java, file, file-io

I'm simply trying to write my output to a File, and am using `FileWriter`;

```
File file = new File("data.txt");
FileWriter output = null;

try
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    output = new FileWriter("Output.txt");
    ....
```

So when I write my `String` results, it's just:

```
output.write("CONFIRMED ");
```

But how do I print the objects? i.e.

```
output.write(student);
```

I was originally using `student.print()`, with the classes:

For the `Student` class:

```
public void print()
{
    System.out.print(studentID + " "  + studentName + " ");
}
```

And for the `Node` class:

```
public void print()
{
    item.print();
    if(next != null)
    {
       next.print();
    }
}
```

Do I have to import `FileWriter` into these classes as well?
I was thinking of making the `print()` methods into `toString()` methods, but I'm unsure of how to change that for the `Node` class because it uses the `print()` method internally.

Comment: What's `item` and `next`?

Answer (score 0):

You could generalize `Student.print()` and `Node.print()` and let them accept a `PrintWriter`

```
 public class Student {
     public void print(PrintWriter out) {
          out.print(studentID + " "  + studentName + " ");
     }
 }
```

Then they are more useful and not tied to System.out.
With this you can create a `PrintWriter` wrapping your `FileWriter` and call those print methods:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("Output.txt"));
...
student.print(out);
```

Comment: OR override toString() and handle the writing outside the object entirely by passing obj.toString() result to the writer. The above approach is better though for objects with large amounts of data to be printed. However from a design perspective might be better to move the print() to an interface. Something like Student implements Printable that declares print() method.

Comment: Thank you @wero! I think I'm going to try something like that. @ShireResident, How would I do that though?

Comment: @user180708 replace "CONFIRMED" with student.toString()?